# Crear array a partir de otros arrays en javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```
[
    {
        measures: [
            { "index":0, "date":"2019-09-25 07:41:21", "X" : 0 },
            { "index":1, "date":"2019-09-25 07:41:22", "X" : 0.00017172 },
            { "index":2, "date":"2019-09-25 07:41:23", "X" : 0.00114484 },
        ], id: "1"
    },
    {
        measures: [
            { "index":0, "date":"2019-09-25 07:41:21", "Y" : 0 },
            { "index":1, "date":"2019-09-25 07:41:22", "Y" : 0.00028542 },
            { "index":2, "date":"2019-09-25 07:41:23", "Y" : 0.00035212 },
        ], id: "2"
    },
    {
        measures: [
            { "index":0, "date":"2019-09-25 07:41:21", "Z" : 0 },
            { "index":1, "date":"2019-09-25 07:41:22", "Z" : 0.02584136 },
            { "index":2, "date":"2019-09-25 07:41:23", "Z" : 0.02696352 },
        ], id: "1"
    },
]
```

Dentro del arreglo measures la última clave es una clave dinámica, en este caso es "X" para el elemento 0, "Y" para el elemento 1 y "Z" para el elemento 2, necesito a partir de los arreglos measures que están dentro del arreglo principal, crear un nuevo arreglo que quede de la siguiente forma:

```
[
    {
        "index": 0,
        "date": 2019-09-25 07:41:21,
        "X" : 0,
        "Y" : 0,
        "Z" : 0
    },
    {
        "index": 1,
        "date": 2019-09-25 07:41:22,
        "X" : 0.00017172,
        "Y" : 0.00028542,
        "Z" : 0.02584136
    },
    {
        "index": 2,
        "date": 2019-09-25 07:41:23,
        "X" : 0.00114484,
        "Y" : 0.00035212,
        "Z" : 0.02696352
    }
]
```

No sé si recorrer los arreglos en paralelo e ir creando el nuevo sea la forma más eficiente de hacerlo o habrá alguna otra forma en que se pueda hacer.

Comment: Podrías explicarme de otra forma lo que dijiste de las posiciones? Me perdí cuál es cuál y al llamarlos elementos no sé a qué te refieras... saludos

Comment: También deberías compartir tu código para recorrer los arreglos.

Comment: @FernandoTorres Hola, gracias por preguntar, El arreglo principal es un arreglo de 3 elementos, cada elemento es un objeto que tiene 2 claves, measures e id. La clave measures es otro arreglo de objetos, y está compuesto por 3 claves, index, date y una tercera clave que es dinámica, es decir, la clave puede cambiar, en este caso en un array es "X", en otro "Y" y en el otro "Z"

Comment: Ok, ya te entendí, te estoy redactando una respuesta

Comment: Yo te preguntaría, ¿los tres elementos siempre son estáticos o puede haber más elementos en tu arreglo original? Lo digo porque pues si son estáticos es más complicado recorrerlos que recorrerlos

Comment: @FernandoTorres En el arreglo original siempre vienen 3 elementos

Comment: ¿Puede variar el número de objetos measures en el array?

Comment: @FernandoTorres cada objeto del array principal tiene dos atributos, measures e id, la longitud de measures es variable, la del array principal no, en el array principal siempre son 3 elementos, en el array measures pueden haber cientos de miles de objetos pero todos con la misma estructura, lo único variable es la última key que puede cambiar porque es dinámica

Answer (score 0):

lo resolví de la siguiente forma haciendo uso de lodash y siguiendo este post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091975/how-to-use-lodash-to-merge-two-collections-based-on-a-key

```
let arr1 = arrayprincipal[0].measures;
let arr2 = arrayprincipal[1].measures;
let arr3 = arrayprincipal[2].measures;
let arrayMerge = _.merge(_.keyBy(arr1, 'index'),_.keyBy(arr2,'index'),_.keyBy(arr3,'index'));
let arrayResult = Object.keys(arrayMerge).map(function (key){
    return arrayMerge[key];
})
```

Si alguien tiene una forma más eficiente y elegante de hacerlo, se agradece el aporte.