# Crear un arreglo de objetos a partir de otro

Tags: javascript, array, json, javascript-objeto, javascript-import

Hola a todos tengo un inconveniente para crear un nuevo arreglo de objetos a partir de otro.
Tengo este primer arreglo que tiene un title, icon, menu y ruta, lo que necesito es que los title repetidos se eliminen y que se cree un children que contendrá el menu y ruta de los objetos eliminados.

```
let listado =[{
        title: 'MANTENIMIENTO',
        icon: 'UsersIcon',
        menu: 'TIPO SERVICIO',
        ruta: 'serviceType'
      },
      {
        title: 'MANTENIMIENTO',
        icon: 'UsersIcon',
        menu: 'USUARIO NEGOCIO',
        ruta: 'businessUser'
      },
      {
        title: 'MANTENIMIENTO',
        icon: 'UsersIcon',
        menu: 'UNIDAD NEGOCIO',
        ruta: 'businessUnit'
      },
      {
        title: 'PRODUCTOS',
        icon: 'BoxIcon',
        menu: 'GRUPO UNIDAD',
        ruta: 'unitGroup'
      },
      {
        title: 'PRODUCTOS',
        icon: 'BoxIcon',
        menu: 'UNIDAD MEDIDA',
        ruta: 'unitMeasure'
      },
      {
        title: 'PRODUCTOS',
        icon: 'BoxIcon',
        menu: 'TIPO PRODUCTO',
        ruta: 'productType'
      }]
```

deseo formar un nuevo arreglo de objetos algo así

```
[{
    title: 'MANTENIMIENTO',
    icon: 'UsersIcon',
    children:[
    {
      menu: 'TIPO SERVICIO',
      ruta: 'serviceType'
    },
    {
      menu: 'UNIDAD NEGOCIO',
      ruta: 'businessUnit'
    },

    ]  
  },
 {
    title: 'PRODUCTOS',
    icon: 'BoxIcon',
    children:[
    {
      menu: 'GRUPO UNIDAD',
      ruta: 'unitGroup'
    },
    {
      menu: 'UNIDAD MEDIDA',
      ruta: 'unitMeasure'
    },
    ]
  },
]
```

quise hacerlo con filter y map pero soy algo nuevo con esto, espero puedan darme alguna idea de como solucionar el problema.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a este enlace, puede que te sea útil: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/323393/crear-array-a-partir-de-otros-arrays-en-javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/323393/crear-array-a-partir-de-otros-arrays-en-javascript)

Comment: Buenas compañero, he encontrado estos ejemplos... Hay uno que no está marcado que es super potente... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects  tienes que buscar "GroupBy one-liner, a ES2021 solution"

Comment: Por favor comparte qué has intentado hasta el momento